# With Office 365 installed adobe reader's send file command doesn't work

Tags: email, adobe-reader

I've got `Adobe Reader` version `11.0.06` installed.

I also have 64bit `Office 365` with `Outlook` installed on my machine.

Whenever I click the email button on reader to email the pdf I get the following dialog.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Office Outlook
---------------------------
Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the     messaging request.  Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I've tried the registry hack spelled out [here](http://nuance-community.custhelp.com/posts/42f6863d2c) and I've tried repairing the office install.

What else should I be trying??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we have this solved thought the solution is less than satisfying.

Steps taken:

```
1) Add a registry key like so:

Add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook
Add the string Key: "Bitness"
Add the value "x64" to the key

2) repair your office 2013 install

3) repair your adobe reader install.
```